# Which caching approach should I use?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

Reading on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/caching_with_rails.html

I've got a PagesController with a home action.

The home view, displays a list of photos, videos and events. Which kind of caching is most suitable for this page?

At first glance, I was thinking of using a fragment cache approach for each model, since the home page displays a list of 3 models (photos, videos and events).

What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, a fragment cache keyed by both the model class name, and the id would be the best given your parameters.